# how to set up property of an object and return a string list

Tags: c#

Add a property method for a Role object named Personnel; this property method has a get block that returns all the
personnel full names for that role in a collection of type List.

How do I do this?

these are the tables :

[image]

i tried making it like this :

```
public static Roles Personnel(int id, out string status)
        {

            get
            {

                status = "Names Found";
                var listString = new List<string>();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = Data.con;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select * from Personnel Join MovieRole on MovieRole.personnelID = Personnel.ID JOIN Role on Role.ID = MovieRole.roleID where Role.ID = " + id.ToString();
                try
                {
                    //Open the connection
                    Data.con.Open();
                    //Execute the command

                    SqlDataReader records = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    //Check to see if record exist
                    while (records.Read())
                    {
                        Roles r = new Roles(Convert.ToInt32(records[0]));
                        r.FirstName = records[1].ToString() + records[3].ToString();
                        listString.Add(r.ToString());
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex) { status = ex.Message; }
                finally
                {
                    //make sure the connection is closed
                    if (Data.con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
                        Data.con.Close();
                }
                return listString;

            }
        }
```

Comment: This better remains a method and shouldn't be turned into a property. It behaves like a method, e.g., it has heavy side-effects like accessing a database. This is not a candidate for a property. Properties should at best only have very light-weight side-effects, which is not the case here. (And then there is the issue of you trying to declare parameters `id` and `status` which is totally nonsenical for properties and won't be accepted by the compiler, because property setters only accept one implicit parameter, one that isn't declared explicitly, that is accessible through the `value` keyword)

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability in your code. It must be remediated. In general properties should not be so complex. They can be trivial or a little complicated, but a database query in a try/catch seems a bit much. We don't see enough of your code to see where the query belongs, though

Comment: Also, you aren't disposing of your `IDisposable` objects, so you'll leak native/system resources (such as open DB connections). You need to wrap every `SqlConnection`, `SqlCOmmand`, and `SqlDataReader` in a `using()` block.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such type of thing like property method in c#. Either we have property or method.

I think you are trying to say about the thing that might be an indexed default property in c#. in indexed property, getter with a parameter would look just like a method.

But Indexer is not required in your case because your requirement is different.

[Click on this for more details.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-properties)

Please see image

[image]

Comment: _"There is no such type of thing like property method in c#."_ - not quite: it's perfectly valid for a C# class to have a property that returns a delegate which can then be invoked, e.g. `class Foo { public Func<Int32> FuncProperty => () => 123; }` as in `Console.WriteLine( new Foo().FuncProperty() );` will print `123`.

Comment: yes I agree @Dai put see syntax :- accessor returntype nameofproperty { get; set;} but in question public(accessor) static roles(return type) nameofproperty(personnel) parameters((int id, out string status)).
if property return delegate then syntax looks like 

accessor(public) static returntype (**delegate( for example :-xyz(parameters)**) nameofproperty(personnel)

Please refer my link

parameters does not come after nameofproperty. in question, mentioned propertymethod not delegate. Can you share me link or example which support the syntax which is written in  question

Comment: I have added image for reference. property cannot have parameter with getter.